# Attach (not embed) an image file to an email being sent by ASP-Classic CDOSYS

Tags: email, asp-classic

I'm trying to attach (not embed) an image file to an email being sent by ASP-Classic CDOSYS from my website.  All the documentation says it's simple. Just use AddAttachment.

. . . . partial code . . .

```
With objMail
  .AddAttachment "E:\xxx.com\files\image\photos\members\me.jpg"
  .Update
End With
```

When the email arrives the file shows up with the email as an attachment, "me.jpg", but the path apparently gets lost during the Add because the attached file size is only a few bytes.

This method works fine for files such as a PDF, Word, or Excel file but not for images.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `.AddAttachment Server.MapPath(...path...)` (and if said path is correct, it's unlikely to contain anything .com).

Comment: Thanks, Martha.  The path in my example was generated from a Server.MapPath command,  My shared hosting environment causes the inclusion of the .com.  I'm confident the path is correct.

Comment: Well, in that case, I got nuttin'. Sorry. :/ (Although, is it possible that it's your mail program that's pretending to be smarter than you and handling .jpg files differently? What happens if you try to attach an .html file to an email?)